# C++ get PID using system

Tags: c++, windows, pid

I am running a file using `system`, but I don't know how to get the PID of that process. Does anybody know how to?

Comment: @In silico:  Why did you add the 'windows' tag?  Do you have some knowledge about OP's situation that the rest of us don't?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use fork and exec instead of system. The child process pid will be returned from fork to the parent process.

**Edit** in case it wasn't obvious, my answer was before the author tagged his post with windows. My answer is specific to Linux.

Comment: But I would say, the same logic applies even though functions the OPer has to use are not fork and exec but Windows API func instead. Usually (not always, but often) system is a bad idea, expecially if you want some kind of "control"